# Showing output of find command with -exec

Tags: bash, find

How would I be able to capture the output from this find command. When I run it, it does not show anything - however files are being zipped up.

```
find /home/casper/foo.* -type f  ! -name *gz  -mtime +7 -exec gzip {} \;
```

Comment: What output were you expecting to see?

Comment: What output do you expect? If you want the names of the files being compressed, add `-print` to the command. `-print` is assumed if no other similar primary (like `-exec`) is supplied, but you can always add it explicitly in addition to the others.

Comment: @John1024 - a listing of the files that were being zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--verbose` to your `gzip` command.